# What is the Jehovah's Witness official viewpoint of 12-step programs like AA?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

I've been meeting with a Jehovah's Witness lately for some study. I've asked questions similar to this and not received a clear/official answer - just an opinion. I've searched Google and only found the opinions and experiences of Witnesses who secretly use AA (Alcoholics Anonymous) or ex-Witnesses sharing their ideas. From those stories I think I have an idea of what the answer is, but I'm wondering what the official stance is (and why) if one exists.

Comment: One of the best tools for researching the beliefs of Jehovah's Witnesses is wol.jw.org (Watchtower Online Library). Any useful results on Google will be from that website or from the main site, jw.org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An article entitled “Breaking the Chains of Alcohol Abuse” in a 2005 [Awake article](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/102005723#h=2)
gives some excellent advice to those struggling to overcome alcoholism.
In it, we find an acknowledgment that many will need professional help to get well.

Then we read what is an official statement about organizations that offer help:

> There are many treatment centers, hospitals, and recovery programs that can provide help. Jehovah’s Witnesses do not endorse any particular treatment. Care must be exercised so that one does not become involved in activities that would compromise Scriptural principles. In the final analysis, however, each will have to decide for himself what type of treatment is needed.

There is a similar statement  in a 2010 [Watchtower article](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2010003#h=31) entitled “Keeping Alcohol in its Place”